# Error in SQL syntax [function in node-red]

Tags: mysql, sql, node-red, msg

I'm trying to post the data into database through node-red but I got this error.

> "Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'insert into customizations(custom_id, product_id, paper_id, ribbon_id, custom_qt' at line 1"

This is the function I used.

```
var items    = msg.payload.items;
var sql = "";
var template = "insert into customizations(custom_id, product_id, paper_id, ribbon_id, custom_qty, message)";
template    += " values(null,'c1','c2','c3','c4','c5')";

for(var i=0;i<items.length;i++){
var cp = template;
cp = cp.replace('c1',items[i].autoId);
cp = cp.replace('c2',items[i].paper_id);
cp = cp.replace('c3',items[i].ribbon_id);
cp = cp.replace('c2',items[i].qty);
cp = cp.replace('c3',items[i].message);
sql += cp;
}


msg.topic = sql;
return msg;
```

Comment: How does the final template look? (I.e. the INSERT actually passed to MySQL.)

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? It looks like you concatenate multiple queries without seperating them by a semicolon

Comment: you miss a space between table name and fields: `customizations (custom_id,`, also you need to terminate your query with ';': `'c4','c5');";` Also, I don't know where your varaibles are coming from but string interpolation opens you to **SQL injections**. You should use prepared statements that would also save you a lot of headache in building the query string or performing multiple queries like this.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm gonna learn more about prepared statements. By the way, It's now working! I literally forgot a space and semicolon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It's extremely bad habit to use replace or any string operations to insert values to your SQL. Read your manual to learn how to `PREPARE` statement once and then execute the prepared statement inside your loop.
2. You have mixed `c2`, `c3`, `c4` and `c5` in replace section.
3. Your syntax error is that SQL statements should end with semicolon (`;`)

Comment: I like the way Python psycopg2 library documentation puts the issue on this replace/string operations: "Warning Never, never, NEVER use Python string concatenation (+) or string parameters interpolation (%) to pass variables to a SQL query string. Not even at gunpoint."

Comment: Thank you so much! It's now working. I just noticed that I duplicated c2 and c3.

Answer (score 0):

There is usually a space after values but it probably don't matter.  You replace c2 and c3 twice.  Use [bind variables](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#escaping-query-values) instead of text interpolation.  It takes care of escaping for you in case any of those fields like message contains a quote:

```
connection.query('insert into customizations(product_id, paper_id, ribbon_id, custom_qty, message) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', [items[i].autoId, items[i].paper_id, items[i].ribbon_id, items[i].qty, items[i].message], ...)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, A space was really forgot. 